# The 'manifest_version' key must be present and set to 2 (without quotes)

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

### MY CODE

```json
{
  "name": "chromeExtTest",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
}
```

It says I need to set it to 2 which I DID but it still gives the error.

Comment: Assuming there's no dangling comma in the actual manifest.json, I guess you probably look at the list of error in chrome://extensions page in which case it's an old error so click the `clear all` button and then reload the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the comma after the 2? If that is the last item, there should be no comma there.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem was It didnt save the code.

Comment: These types of "problems" are closed as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.